# WCF REST Service for ANdroid Client Producing Error

Tags: c#, android, wcf, rest

Hi I want to make a WCF Rest service to be consumed by an android client.
Can somebody please post a easy helpful solution for the same problem step by step.

As far as I see 
Web.config:

```
<service name="ServifyCoreModulesService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="ServifyCoreModulesService.IService1" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/service1" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
```

App.config:

```
<client>
    <endpoint
      name="endpoint1"
      address="http://localhost/ServifyCoreModulesService/Service1.svc"
      binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration=""
      behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
      contract="ServifyCoreModulesService.IService1" >

      <metadata>
        <wsdlImporters>
          <extension
            type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.WsdlDocumentationImporter, WsdlDocumentation"/>
        </wsdlImporters>
      </metadata>

      <identity>
        <servicePrincipalName value="host/localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    </client>
```

I am getting issue with metadata.
I dont understand all of these tags does anybody have a start to finish tutorial on this ? Or any clue about why i should configure in a particular way?

Comment: REST services don't normally use WSDL - it looks like you're trying to treat a REST service as a SOAP service.  What led you to set up the client config the way you show?

Comment: Can you please suggest how to configure client.config for a REST service? I got the error endpoint not defined so i thought of configuring the client somehow to resolve the error...How should i proceed with this?